# maximum number of classes for ColumnDataClassifier

Tags: classification, stanford-nlp, text-classification

Is there a limit on the maximum number of classes i can have in using ColumnDataClassifier? I have about addresses that I want to assign to 10k orgs, but i kept running into memory issue even after I set the -xmx number to maximum.

Comment: How many labels do you want to apply to the 10k organizations ?  Are you trying to read in the text of the name of an organization and then label it?

Comment: No, the input is address of an organization, say "450 Serra Mall, Stanford, CA 94305", the output (label) is "Stanford University". I have 10k of such labels. I couldn't stop the OOM unless I limit my features to less than about 2500. But that will hurt the accuracy a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an explicit limit for the size of the label set, but 10k is an extremely large set, and I am not surprised you are having memory issues.  You should try some experiments with substantially smaller label sets (~ 100 labels) and see if your issues go away.  I don't know how many labels will practically work, but I doubt it's anywhere near 10,000.  I would try much smaller sets just to understand how the memory usage is growing at the label set size grows.

You may have to have a hierarchy of labels and different classifiers.  You could imagine the first label being "California-organization", and then having a second classifier to select the various California organizations, etc...

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful. So do you mean that  I need to train, say for example, one model for California, one model for Texas etc?

Comment: Sure.  You need to have a much smaller set of labels for your classifier.  So arranging the labels into a hierarchy could allow you to perform the same 10,000 label classification with a sequence of classifiers.